# How to find out which action is triggered by change text color button in tinyMCE and how to link it with my custom button?

Tags: javascript, html, tinymce, console.log

I am trying to use tinyMCE in my project, i know how to add features to editor in editor init f.ex.:

```
toolbar: '| forecolor backcolor removeformat |',
```

But I have my own custumized toolbar which is totaly separate from tinyMCE editor (I have built it in HTML). So I have button which is supposed to change color of selected text, the question is how link my custom button with action which is triggered by original tinyMCE toolbar icon for changing forecolor?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add some code to your TinyMCE configuration to see when a command is issued in TinyMCE.

```
setup: function(editor) {
    editor.on('ExecCommand', function (e) {
        console.log('ExecCommand:', e);
    });
}
```

This will output something to the browser's console when a TinyMCE command is run.  When you update the text color (via the `forecolor` toolbar button) you see a command like this:

```
ExecCommand: {
  command: "mceApplyTextcolor", 
  ui: "forecolor", 
  value: "#2DC26B", 
  type: "execcommand", 
  target: EE, 
  …
}
```

I have created a TinyMCE Fiddle that shows how you can use execCommand to perform this same work from your own custom code:

https://fiddle.tiny.cloud/Hxhaab/2